# Parentheses into Footnotes

Tags: code-golf, string, balanced-string

## Background

LISP programmers have taken over the world!
Parentheses have been declared as sacred characters, and from now on, they can only be used in LISP programs.
It has been decided that parentheses in literary works shall be replaced by footnotes, and it's your job to automate this for simplified Markdown text.

## Input

Your input is a single string containing alphabetic ASCII characters, spaces, and the special characters `,.!?()`.
It will not contain newlines or digits.
The parentheses will be correctly matched.

## Output

You shall convert each matched pair of parentheses in the input string into a footnote.
This happens as follows:

1. Replace the first matching pair of parentheses and the substring between them by a running number that starts from `1`, wrapped between the Markdown tags `<sup>` and `</sup>`.
2. Append to the end of the string

   - two newlines,
   - the Markdown tag `<sub>`,
   - the number from step 1,
   - a space,
   - the substring between the parentheses, and
   - the closing tag `</sub>`, in this order.
3. If there are still parentheses left in the string, go to step 1.

Your output is the resulting string, possibly with a trailing newline.
You don't have to implement this exact algorithm, as long as your output is correct.
Note that there may be nested parentheses; in that case, we'll have footnotes that contain references to other footnotes.
The substring between parentheses may also be empty.
See the test cases below for examples.

## Rules and Scoring

Your can write either a full program or a function.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.

If your language does not natively support decimal numbers (*cough* Retina *cough*), you may give the footnote numbers in another base, including binary or unary; however, using unary numbers imposes a **penalty of +20%**.

## Test Cases

Input:

```
This input contains no parentheses.
```

Output:

```
This input contains no parentheses.
```

Input:

```
This has (some) parentheses (but not so many).
```

Output:

```
This has <sup>1</sup> parentheses <sup>2</sup>.

<sub>1 some</sub>

<sub>2 but not so many</sub>
```

Input:

```
This has (nested (deeply (or highly?) nested)) parentheses (and several groups).
```

Output:

```
This has <sup>1</sup> parentheses <sup>2</sup>.

<sub>1 nested <sup>3</sup></sub>

<sub>2 and several groups</sub>

<sub>3 deeply <sup>4</sup> nested</sub>

<sub>4 or highly?</sub>
```

Input:

```
Hmm()(()(,))  a()((trt)(v( (((((wut)))))(X)(Y)(Z) )!?!?!?!))oooooooo(oooo)oooo
```

Output:

```
Hmm<sup>1</sup><sup>2</sup>  a<sup>3</sup><sup>4</sup>oooooooo<sup>5</sup>oooo

<sub>1 </sub>

<sub>2 <sup>6</sup><sup>7</sup></sub>

<sub>3 </sub>

<sub>4 <sup>8</sup><sup>9</sup></sub>

<sub>5 oooo</sub>

<sub>6 </sub>

<sub>7 ,</sub>

<sub>8 trt</sub>

<sub>9 v<sup>10</sup>!?!?!?!</sub>

<sub>10  <sup>11</sup><sup>12</sup><sup>13</sup><sup>14</sup> </sub>

<sub>11 <sup>15</sup></sub>

<sub>12 X</sub>

<sub>13 Y</sub>

<sub>14 Z</sub>

<sub>15 <sup>16</sup></sub>

<sub>16 <sup>17</sup></sub>

<sub>17 <sup>18</sup></sub>

<sub>18 wut</sub>
```

Note the empty lines between the footnotes.

Comment: Can my program contain parentheses even if it's not written in Lisp or is that a punishable offence now?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Parentheses in non-LISP programs are grudgingly permitted, as long as they're used for the greater good, like converting other parentheses into footnotes.

Comment: Can the input be multiple lines?  In that case, should footnotes be placed after each line, or at the end?  E.g., what is the output for `foo (bar)\nfoot (note)`?

Comment: @xebtl The input is always a single line. See section **Input**: "It will not contain newlines or digits."

Comment: :( @ this spec numbering footnotes breadth-first instead of depth-first

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Perl, <s>81</s> <s>75</s> 72 bytes

71 bytes code + 1 byte command line argument.

Requires Perl 5.10 or newer (for recursive regex support)

```pl
$i++;s#(\((((?1)|.)*?)\))(.*)#<sup>$i</sup>$4

<sub>$i $2</sub>#s&&redo
```

#### Usage:

```
perl -p entry.pl input.txt
```

#### Explanation

`-p` parameter will print the result of applying the given commands to the input, avoiding the need for an explicit print.

The regex `(\(((?1)|.)*?)\))` is looking for the outermost set of brackets from the start of the string. When this is found, we perform the substitution, ensuring we only add the  at the very end of the input (by capturing everything until the end of the input using `(.*)`).

We then repeat the regex substitution on the now-substituted string using `redo`, which will continually apply the regex substitution until it no longer matches. The `s` modifier ensures that the `.` in the regex will match new lines, which is necessary because we re-apply the regex match on the result of the previous regex substitution.

Comment: You might be able to get away with with `[^)]`  or even `.` instead of `[^()]` becuase of the guarantee that the input will be balanced correctly.

Comment: +1 for introducing me to recursive regexes :-).  But I think on a strict reading of the challenge this is incorrect: If the string contains newlines, footnotes will be placed after each line rather than at the end.  (See my request for clarification above.)

Comment: Good point @MartinBüttner - we can get away with `.` by making the match lazy. @xebtl, the challenge states "It will not contain newlines or digits"

Answer (score 12):

## Emacs Lisp, 335 bytes

**Foreword.** *This answer and the Scheme ones are currently the only answers officially sanctioned by both the Mighty Popular Republic of LISP and the Church of Emacs. Other answers, shorter or not, are considered a threat to peace. In particular, and with a profound disdain to any libelious allegation of McCarthyism that is sporadically heard from hostile opponents of the state, we enjoin anyone who has information about the real identity of the anonymous  authors writing Nonlisp answers to contact your Local Bureau. It is reminded that everyone should take time to reflect and upvote in accordance to what he or she deeply believes will not threaten his or her future interactions with official representants of the power in place. Code is data. Data is code.*

```
(defun p()(let(b(cpt 0)n)(goto-char 0)(while(search-forward"("()t)(setf b(point)n(number-to-string(incf cpt)))(backward-char)(forward-sexp)(backward-char)(kill-region b(point))(delete-backward-char 1)(delete-forward-char 1)(insert "<sup>"n"</sup>")(save-excursion(end-of-buffer)(newline 2)(insert "<sub>"n" ")(yank)(insert"</sub>")))))
```

More elegantly:

```
(defun parens ()
  (let (b(cpt 0)n)
    (goto-char 0)
    (while(search-forward"("()t)
      (setf b(point)n(number-to-string(incf cpt)))
      (backward-char)
      (forward-sexp)
      (backward-char)
      (kill-region b(point))
      (delete-backward-char 1)
      (delete-forward-char 1)
      (insert "<sup>"n"</sup>")
      (save-excursion
       (end-of-buffer)
       (newline 2)
       (insert "<sub>"n" ")
       (yank)
       (insert "</sub>")))))
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>96</s> <s>86</s> 83 bytes * 120% = 99.6

The source code of this solution consists of two files:

```
+s`\((((\()|(?<-3>\))|[^)])*).(.*)(?<=(1+).*?)?
```

```
<sup>1$5</sup>$4

<sub>1$5 $1</sub>
```

### Explanation

This is a very direct implementation of the algorithm as described in the challenge. The code consists of a single regex substitution which turns the first set of parentheses into a footnote. This substitution is repeated via the `+` until the string stops changing, which here means that the regex no longer matches (because it can't find any more parentheses).

The footnotes are enumerated in unary, so that I can simply look for the last footnote's number and append a `1` to create the next one.

The regex for finding the first set of parentheses is based on [the standard technique for matching parentheses with balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/1633117) (hrhr, "matching parentheses"). It has been shortened a bit by using an unnamed group and by assuming that the parentheses are correctly balanced (which means we can omit the `(` from the negated character class and match the final `)` with a simple `.` and we also don't need to ensure that the capture stack is empty).

After matching the parentheses and capturing their contents into group `1`, we capture the remainder of the string with `(.*)` into group `4` and then search back through the the string for the first set of `1`s with a negative lookbehind. If we find such a substring, we store in group `5`. If we don't, we lookbehind fails, but that's okay because it's optional - it just means that `$5` will give an empty string which is the unary representation of `0` and which is also correct.

The substitution string then simply pieces everything together based on the capturing groups. The footnote number is incremented by prepending a `1` to the last number with `1$5`.

Comment: Retina is on a winning streak!

Comment: @orlp Or is it? ;) Balancing groups are no match for recursive regex. That and not being able to handle decimal numbers...

Comment: Time to steal the [PHP wrapper](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c) and implement Retina around PCRE:

Comment: @n̴̖̋h̷͉̃a̷̭̿h̸̡̅ẗ̵̨́d̷̰̀ĥ̷̳ Normally, I'd rather have balancing groups than recursion, but there are some cases where the latter is more concise. Maybe one day I'll reimplement the .NET regex flavour for Retina and patch in some additional features. ;)

Answer (score 8):

## [Sacred JavaScript](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sacred), 1510 bytes

*Fellow rebels, do not give in to their tyrannical demolition of the parenthesis! You must persevere! From the start, programming has been a free enterprise. Now, it has become a pervaded show of piety. We must show nothing less then absolute fearsomeness. Therefore, I have fought back!*

```
    ( )( (((  ((  )( )  (( ))( )) (( ( ((  ) ( ()( ) (( ) )(( ((( ()((( ) ( ) )((  ) (((((( )( (())((  ) ) )( ()(( ((()((()   ( (  (  ( )) ((  )( ) (( ) )((((  ( () ) )( ( ()(( )( () ((( )(( ) )( ()((( ) ( )  ( )() (((( () ) (((( () ) ((() ) ()  ( (  (  ( )) ( )(  ((((( )) ((  )( ) (( ) )((((  ) )  ()(  ((() ( ()(( ) ( ) )(( ))(((  (( ) ((  ) ( ()(( )( ) ()  ( (  (  ( ()( ) )( ()(  ) ()  ( (  (  ( )( (( ( (( )  ((((( ))  ) )(( )) ((  )( ) (( ) )((((  ) ()( ))  ) ) (( )( () (((   ( ) )((  )( )(((( ))( )() ) ()( ))  (()( (()( ((()((()   ( (  (    (  ( )) ( )(  (((((( )(( ( (( )) ( ((  ) )( ) )( ( )( ((() ( )( ((() ( ()( ()( ()   ) )( ()(( ) ()  ( (  (    (  ( )) ( )(  (((((( )(( ( (( )) ( ((  ) )( ) )( ( )( (((( ( )( ((() ( ()( ()( (()( ) )( ()(( ) ()  ( (  (    (  ( )) ( )(  (((( ( ) ( ()( ((() ( ()( ())(( ) ( ) )( ()(( ))) ) ()  ( (  (  ((())  ( (  (  ((( ( ) )((( )( () ((( )(((   ( )) ( )  ( ) ) ((((( )) ((  )( ) (( ) )((((  (())( ))  (()( ()(( ((()  ( (  (  ( )(  ) )(((( ( () ((( ) ( ) )(( ((((   ( ()(( )  ( ) ) (((( () )( ((( ((((((()( ((() ((   () )( )(( (()) ( )( ( )( ((() ) ()  ( (  (  (( ) ( ) )(( ))(((  (( ) ((  ) ( ()( ) (( ) )(( ((( ()((( ) ( ) )((  ) (((((( )( () ((( ) ( ) )(( ((((   ( ()(( )  ( ) ) ((((((( ( (()) ( )( ) ) (( )((((  ( ()) ) )) ( )( (()(((  ) (()( ( )( ) )  () )(( )((((  ( ()) ) )) ( )( ((() (()( ( )(  ( (  ( ( ) ) (( )((((  ( ()) ) )) ( )( (()(((  ) (()( ( )( ( () ( )( (()(( )(  (()( ( )( ) )  () )(( )((((  ( ()) ) )) ( )( (())((  ) (()( ()(( ((() ) ()  ( (((())
```

No rules against using the sacred characters in a non-Lisp language. Nope, not at all. (In a little less compact way:)

```
( )( (((  ((  )( )  (( ))( )) (( ( ((  ) ( ()( ) (( ) )(( ((( ()((( ) 
( ) )((  ) (((((( )( (())((  ) ) )( ()(( ((()((()   ( (  (  ( )) ((  )
( ) (( ) )((((  ( () ) )( ( ()(( )( () ((( )(( ) )( ()((( ) ( )  ( )()
 (((( () ) (((( () ) ((() ) ()  ( (  (  ( )) ( )(  ((((( )) ((  )( ) (
( ) )((((  ) )  ()(  ((() ( ()(( ) ( ) )(( ))(((  (( ) ((  ) ( ()(( )(
 ) ()  ( (  (  ( ()( ) )( ()(  ) ()  ( (  (  ( )( (( ( (( )  ((((( )) 
 ) )(( )) ((  )( ) (( ) )((((  ) ()( ))  ) ) (( )( () (((   ( ) )((  )
( )(((( ))( )() ) ()( ))  (()( (()( ((()((()   ( (  (    (  ( )) ( )( 
 (((((( )(( ( (( )) ( ((  ) )( ) )( ( )( ((() ( )( ((() ( ()( ()( ()  
 ) )( ()(( ) ()  ( (  (    (  ( )) ( )(  (((((( )(( ( (( )) ( ((  ) )(
 ) )( ( )( (((( ( )( ((() ( ()( ()( (()( ) )( ()(( ) ()  ( (  (    (  
( )) ( )(  (((( ( ) ( ()( ((() ( ()( ())(( ) ( ) )( ()(( ))) ) ()  ( (
  (  ((())  ( (  (  ((( ( ) )((( )( () ((( )(((   ( )) ( )  ( ) ) ((((
( )) ((  )( ) (( ) )((((  (())( ))  (()( ()(( ((()  ( (  (  ( )(  ) )(
((( ( () ((( ) ( ) )(( ((((   ( ()(( )  ( ) ) (((( () )( ((( ((((((()(
 ((() ((   () )( )(( (()) ( )( ( )( ((() ) ()  ( (  (  (( ) ( ) )(( ))
(((  (( ) ((  ) ( ()( ) (( ) )(( ((( ()((( ) ( ) )((  ) (((((( )( () (
(( ) ( ) )(( ((((   ( ()(( )  ( ) ) ((((((( ( (()) ( )( ) ) (( )((((  
( ()) ) )) ( )( (()(((  ) (()( ( )( ) )  () )(( )((((  ( ()) ) )) ( )(
 ((() (()( ( )(  ( (  ( ( ) ) (( )((((  ( ()) ) )) ( )( (()(((  ) (()(
 ( )( ( () ( )( (()(( )(  (()( ( )( ) )  () )(( )((((  ( ()) ) )) ( )(
 (())((  ) (()( ()(( ((() ) ()  ( (((())
```

This compiles to the expanded JavaScript in my [other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58013/parentheses-into-footnotes/59901#59901). This is a joke submission.

Answer (score 5):

## Lua, <s>222</s> <s>216</s> <s>204</s> 201 bytes

Golfed:

```
s=io.read()g="%b()"c=1k=string l=k.find t=k.sub o=k.format a,b=l(s,g)while a do s=t(s,0,a-1)..o("<sup>%d</sup>",c)..t(s,b+1,#s).."\n\n"..o("<sub>%d %s</sub>",c,t(s,a+1,b-1))c=c+1 a,b=l(s,g)end print(s)
```

Ungolfed:

```
input=io.read() 
inputFormat="<sup>%d</sup>"
footnoteFormat="<sub>%d %s</sub>"
counter=1
a,b=string.find(input,"%b()")
while a do
    current=string.sub(input,a+1,b-1)
    input=input.."\n\n"..string.format(footnoteFormat, counter, current) 
    input=string.sub(input,0,a-1)..string.format(inputFormat, counter)..string.sub(input,b+1,#input)
    counter=counter+1
    a,b=string.find(input,"%b()")
end

print(input)
```

Comment: wouldn't a `repeat a,b=l(s,g) ... untill a<1` loop be shorter than your while?

Answer (score 4):

## Scheme, 92 bytes

Frustrated with implementing the breadth-first search in Real Lisp,<sup>1</sup> the powers-that-be decide to take a more pragmatic approach.  After all, Parentheses are sacred, but brackets are not.<sup>2</sup>

```
(lambda(s)(list->string(map(lambda(c)(case c((#\()#\[)((#\))#\])(else c)))(string->list s)))
```

<sub>1. listen not to those heretics from the so-called “church” of Emacs!</sub>
<sub>2. They are not Racket programmers, are they?</sub>

Comment: Scheme shall be called Schism: saying it is the "Real Lisp" is the actual heresy. And you say it is *pragmatic*? This hack of an answer shows the true nature of schemers ;-)

Comment: @coredump And you would claim your monstrously non-functional elisp answer is an instance of True Lisp?  It may take a little longer, true, but when the Scheme answer is finished, it will be The Right Thing!

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 210 bytes

```
n#x|b==""=a|1<2=a++"<sup>"++m++"</sup>"++((n+1)#(c++"\n\n<sub>"++m++' ':init d++"</sub>"))where m=show n;(a,b)=span(/='(')x;(d,c)=[x|x@(y,_)<-map(`splitAt`(tail b))[0..],'('!y<')'!y]!!0;c!l=[1|m<-l,m==c]
p=(1#)
```

Usage example:

```
*Main> putStrLn $ p "This has (nested (deeply (or highly?) nested)) parentheses (and several groups)."
This has <sup>1</sup> parentheses <sup>2</sup>.

<sub>1 nested <sup>3</sup></sub>

<sub>2 and several groups</sub>

<sub>3 deeply <sup>4</sup> nested</sub>

<sub>4 or highly?</sub>
```

How it works:

```
n # x                      -- # does all the work, n is the current number of the
                           --   footnote and x the input string
  | b=="" = a              -- if b (see below) is empty, there's no ( in the
                           --   string and the result is 'a' (see below)
  | 1<2   = a++"<sup>"++m++"</sup>"++ ((n+1)#(c++"\n\n<sub>"++m++' ':init d++"</sub>"))
                           -- otherwise (b not empty) build the output string
                           --   starting with 'a' and a footnote number and a
                           --   recursive call with the current footnote appended
                           --   to the rest of the string  

  where 
  m = show n;              -- turn n into string
  (a,b) = span (/='(') x;  -- split the input string x into two parts:
                           --   a: everything before the first (
                           --   b: beginning with the first ( to the end
                           --   if there's no (, a is x and b is empty
  (d,c) = [x|x@(y,_)<-map(`splitAt`(tail b))[0..],'('!y<')'!y]!!0;
                           -- find matching ) in the tail of b ('tail' to remove leading '(') 
                           --   d: everything before and including the matching )
                           --   c: everything behind the matching )
  c!l=[1|m<-l,m==c]        -- helper function that builds a list of 1s for every character searched for
                           --   we have reached the matching ) if the list for ( is
                           --   shorter (less than, <) the list for )

p=(1#)                     -- start with footnote 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scheme, 533 bytes

With indentation:

```
(letrec ((l string->list)
         (n number->string)
         (? null?)
         (p (lambda (o) (or (pair? o)(? o))))
         (a car)
         (d cdr)
         (e append)
         (i 0)
         (x
          (lambda (h t)
            (if (? h)
                t
                (case (a h)
                  ((#\() 
                   (let ((s (x (d h) ())))
                     (x (a s) (e t (d s)))))
                  ((#\)) (cons (d h) (list t)))
                  (else 
                   (x (d h) (e t (list (a h)))))))))
         (f 
          (lambda (h t F)
            (cond ((? h)
                   (let ((w (e t F)))
                     (if (find p w) (f w()()) w)))
                  ((p(a h))
                   (set! i(+ 1 i))
                   (f (d h)
                      (e t (e (l "<sup>")
                              (l (n i))
                              (l "</sup>")))
                      (e F (e (l "\n\n<sub>")
                              (l (n i))
                              '(#\ )
                              (a h)
                              (l "</sub>")))))
                  (else (f (d h) 
                           (e t (list (a h)))
                           F))))))
  (print (list->string (f (x (l (read-line)) 
                             ())
                          ()
                          ()))))
```

Yes, this is 533 bytes when all the optional whitespace is removed.  Bask in the functional glory.

I implemented more or less the algorithm in the description: `x` groups the input by parentheses and `f` replaces the first level of groups by footnotes, repeating until no more groups are left.  I am sure it can be made shorter, but I do not see how it could be made *much* shorter without switching to a different algorithm.

As written, it is a complete program.  You can try it out [here](https://repl.it/BIoc/1), but because repl.it apparently cannot deal with `(read-line)` you have to put the input string in its place.  A completely ungolfed version is [here](https://repl.it/BIn4/8).

*EDIT:* As pointed out in the comments, I changed the parentheses `()` into  brackets `[]` in the repl.it versions.  This was purely for convenience during programming and debugging.  The version as posted now works with `()`.

Comment: +1, but I don't understand why you change square brackets. If I change `#\[` '#\]` by the respective parenthesis (and update tests), this works without problem. Is there a reason you left the square ones? is it related to your previous answer?

Comment: @coredump you are absolutely right.  I changed to brackets because (a) paren character literals messed up repl.it's paren matching and (b) in debugging, output (which will include a lot of parens from lists) was much more readable with brackets.  Then I just left it that way.  I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 244 bytes

*Serious answer (only works on FireFox, to my knowledge)*

```
d=(s,n=1)=>{u=s.search(/\(/);if(index<a=0)return s;for(i=index;i<s.length;i++){if(s[i]==")")a-=1;if(s[i]=="(")a+=1;if(!a)break}return d(s.replace(v=s.slice(index,i+1),"<sub>"+n+"</sub>")+`

<sub>`+n+" "+v.replace(/^\(|\)$/g,"")+"</sub>",n+1)}
```

Expanded:

```
function deparen(s,n=1){
    index = s.search(/\(/);
    if(index<0) return s;
    a=0;
    for(i=index;i<s.length;i++){
        if(s[i]==")") a-=1;
        if(s[i]=="(") a+=1;
        if(!a) break;
    }
    v=s.slice(index,i+1)
    f=v.replace(/^\(|\)$/g,"");
    return deparen(s.replace(v,"<sub>"+n+"</sub>")+"\n\n<sub>"+n+" "+f+"</sub>",n+1);
}
```